# Shadowing and GCC -Wshadow

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, standards

One cannot underestimate the importance of shadowing warning in C++, however, there is a shadowing warning on something which looks (to me) perfectly valid code.

```
struct A{
    int a;
    A(int a) : a(a){}
};
```

In this case, I dont see how such construct could be interpreted by compiler other than 'class member is being initialized with constructor argument'. So, whats the deal?
[Live on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c4c9fca7b668275e)

Comment: shadowing is not about the compiler being confused as to what declaration a symbol refers to. It's about the human being confused as to what a symbol refers to.

Comment: There is shadowing and you specified -Wshadow. So GCC is doing its job. What's the deal?

Comment: There is no _ambiguity_ in this code because the compiler can figure out which `a` is which `a`, but there _is_ still shadowing. It it unwise to write such code. Give your variables an parameters proper names.

Comment: The compiler could interpret it has member `a` being initialized by member `a`... which is obviously wrong. The Wshadow is not smart enough to see that the shadowed alternative is UB. Probably that many other poeple don't like this warning, it is not included in -Wall. Consider using -Wshadow=local

Comment: @Oliv, right, as it has been already noted below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this code?

```
A(int a) : a(a){ ++a; }
```

Which a is incremented? The argument to the constructor or the member variable?

```
int main() {
  A a(5);
  std::cout << "a.a = " << a.a << std::endl;
}

// gives: a.a = 5
```

Or how about this one?

```
A() : a(a){ }

warning: ‘A::a’ is initialized with itself
```

Shadowing is going on.

Comment: I kind of don't agree with your assessment. First of all, there is no ambiguity with shadowing. If it were then the code wouldn't compile with a message along the lines "call to xxx is ambiguous". Shadowing is not ambiguity. It's about a symbol shadowing another one. No ambiguity: the language is very clear on what a symbol refers to. Second the problem with `++a` is the same problem with `:a(a)` To what does the second `a` refer to? Am I initializing with the parameter `a` or am I initializing `a` with itself. If you know the answer to this you know the answer to `++a` and viceversa.

Comment: You are right, there already is shadowing in the `a(a)` statement. I just tested it and member variables can be initialized by member variables it seems: `A() : a(a) { }` results in "warning: ‘A::a’ is initialized with itself". I thought that wasn't even allowed. Anyway, the example with ++a makes it clearer how hard it is for a human to understand which a is actually referred to.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow, totally missed the possibility of a member being initialized with a member, even itself, then of course, the warning is legitimate. BTW, I think this answer is better describes the situation than the increment example you gave.